# Identifying the transitive match records in oracle SQL

Tags: sql

**SOURCE**

| Rowid_object | Rowid_object_matched |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 6 | 5 |
| 7 | 8 |
| 9 | 8 |

**Target**

| Rowid_object | Rowid_object_matched |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 7 | 7 |
| 8 | 7 |
| 9 | 7 |

Here, we have **Source** like data and we want **Target** like result.

There are two groups in source which are in transitive match.

Need to identify these kind of record.

Comment: MySQL and Oracle are two completely different DBMS'. Add only the tag corresponding to the DBMS you're currently using.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can use:

```sql
SELECT rowid_object,
       MIN(root) AS rowid_object_matched
FROM   (
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT(rowid_object) AS root,
         rowid_object,
         rowid_object_matched
  FROM   source
  CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
         PRIOR rowid_object IN (rowid_object, rowid_object_matched)
  OR     PRIOR rowid_object_matched IN (rowid_object, rowid_object_matched)
)
UNPIVOT (
  rowid_object FOR key IN (rowid_object, rowid_object_matched)
)
GROUP BY rowid_object;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE SOURCE (Rowid_object, Rowid_object_matched) AS
SELECT 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9, 8 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ROWID_OBJECT | ROWID_OBJECT_MATCHED |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 |
| 7 | 7 |
| 8 | 7 |
| 9 | 7 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FUuT80I4)